# What is the expected number of card draws to get all four suits (with replacement)?

Tags: probability

Imagine I am drawing cards (with replacement) from a standard deck (52 cards, 13 of each suit).  I am trying to compute the expected number of cards I will need to draw in order to have at least one card of each suit.

My computer simulation tells me that the answer is 8.3, but I have no idea how to solve the problem using math.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Solution: Thanks to Byron Schmuland who pointed me in the direction of the correct answer.

By linearity of expectation,

E(number of cards to get all suits) = E(number of cards to get 1 suit) + E(number to get a different suit) + E(number to get a third different suit) +  E(number to get a 4th different suit)

E(number of cards to get 1 suit) = 1

E(number to get a different suit) = 1/(3/4) = 4/3  (by the geometric distribution)

E(number to get a 3rd different suit) = 1/(2/4) = 4/2

E(number to get a 4th different suit) = 1/(1/4) = 4

1 + 4/3 + 4/2 + 4 = 8.3333

Comment: This is the coupon collector's problem. The theoretical answer is  8.3333 which suggests that your simulation is way off. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Comment: Ok, I will check my code :)  Meanwhile, would someone provide the solution?

Comment: Found the bug.  It is indeed 8.3 :)  Thanks for the tip about the coupon collector's problem.  I will write up a solution once I have fully understood it.

Comment: It's only the coupon collector problem if the card deck is infinite.  For a 52-card deck the answer will be different.

Comment: I think it is the coupon collector problem, because the cards are drawn with replacement.  So in a sense, the deck is infinite.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right.  I didn't realize that you were drawing with replacement.